# Tolerant doesn't appear to grant Terran equivalent population cap

Tags: master-of-orion-2

In Master of Orion II, if you have/take Tolerant as a racial trait it says that you treat all worlds as Terran for purposes of max population according to the tooltip. This does not seem to be the case however, rather you appear to get an increase in cap but not up to Terran level. For instance, a Medium Barren planet will normally have a cap of 4. With Tolerant that doubles to 8. A Medium Terran without Tolerant has a cap of 12 population. With Tolerant that increases to a cap of 15.

Was this change in a patch somewhere along the line or was the tooltip wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooltip was wrong. Quoting:

> ### Environmentally Tolerant
>
> Cost[10]: These races typically regenerate, or have a metabolism quite unlike that of a standard humanoid. **Races that are environmentally tolerant treat all planet environments as Terran for purposes of maximum population**. Tolerant races also ignore pollution, not spending any industry to clean it up. On multi-racial colonies, the proportion of non-tolerant to tolerant population determines the amount of pollution that must be cleaned. For example, If there are 3 tolerant and 7 non-tolerant population units 7/10 of the pollution must be cleaned up.

The next relevant quote is from the Master of Orion II Instruction Manual, pg. 25, a version of which can be found [here](http://www.moo3.at/moo2/files.php):

> ### Tolerant
>
> means that a race is practically immune to extreme
>   environments. Typically, these races have strong regenerative
>   properties or a metabolism quite unlike that of the average humanoid.
>   **Races that are tolerant can use 25% more of a planet's surface for
>   habitation**, living in places no other race would dare and boosting the
>   planet's maximum potential population. **Thus, for example, while a
>   typical race could live on 25% of a Barren planet, a Tolerant race could
>   use 50% of the same planet**. Tolerant races also suffer no harm from
>   pollution and need not spend production resources cleaning it up.

Note the differences, which I've highlighted. According to the manual, Tolerant races can use 25% more of the planet's surface for population purposes, which is the observed effect.

There is some contradicting information on the web regarding this topic but [this post](http://masteroforion2.blogspot.pt/2005/10/maximum-population.html) pretty much sums the correct "science" behind population and planets. Summing up, for the Tolerant case:

- Planets have different sizes and to each size a class is given.
- The maximum population that planet can hold (without picks) is equal to 5 times the planet's size class and corresponds to a Gaia environment.
- Different environments lower the maximum population of a planet by a fixed percentage. For example, a Barren planet can hold 25% and a Terran planet 80% of its maximum population.
- *Tolerant* increases that percentage by a value of 25%. Following the example, this means that a Barren Planet in the hands of a Tolerant race is able to support 50% of its maximum population. A Terran planet with a Tolerant race is now able to support the full 100% (as it doesn't make sense to support the extra 5%).

I didn't find any change on the patch lists regarding the different descriptions, but I would assume that the manual (despite lacking in information) was a result of a consolidated game mechanic. The tooltip may have been a leftover from an earlier design stage of the game, because if following the in-game tooltip to the letter, Tolerant races would not acquire the population benefits of Gaia planets and Gaia Transformation.

Comment: The 25% is inline with the Silicoids from the first game, I should have figured.

Comment: IIRC, in the original MOO, the Silicoids had a similar effect, but it wasn't 25%. Rather, they could colonize every planet from the start, while every other race had to develop specific colony modules for specific environments. With advancements in Planetology, the Silicoids' advantage fades away.